# How to add Mono X to an existing ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

I have an existing ASP.NET 4.0 website and am contemplating using MonoX for our CMS. Is there any way to install MonoX as a subdirectory in the existing website? I know I can have two websites in the same project, but I'd like to be able to reference some master pages and possibly other things in MonoX from the existing website without relying on virtual directories.

Comment: The mono tag is for something completely different. Don't misuse it.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for letting me know.